# How to get a request with spaces in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Send data to the server:

```
'   test_data   '
```

In `Request $request` come:

```
'test_data   '
```

How to get data with spaces (do not trim them)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Completely disable the `TrimStrings` middleware by commenting it out from the `Kernel` class:

```php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class, <-- This is the middleware
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

// [...]
```

2. If you just need to avoid the trim of specific inputs, you have to update the `TrimStrings` middleware:

```php
class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
        'first_input',
        'another_input', // Here add your inputs
        'my_other_input'
    ];

// [...]
```

Comment: Just to add to this: if the string trimming is happening inside an argument that is json/arbitrarily named and nested, the `$except` value won't quite be able to catch it, because the keys considered look like `attribute_name.other_key` and never just `attribute_name`. In that case you can override `protected function transform(`, following the example of the parent class, do your custom filtering, and then call `return parent::transform($key, $value);` for the other cases.