# Laravel, space as value in POST param

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

hi how can i allow `space` in post param for specific route/param in laravel 10?

i have found a lot of solutions like comment `TrimStrings` in `Kernel.php` or adding `expect` in `TrimString` class (i added `numbering.invoice.priceFormat.decimal` as value) but nothing seems to work at all :/

- [How to get a request with spaces in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077756/how-to-get-a-request-with-spaces-in-laravel)

maybe issue is that i have nested values

my post data are sent in `numbering.invoice.priceFormat.decimal` with rules `required|string`

also i want to send `decimal` as `space` so my request looks like this

```json
{
    "numbering": {
        "invoice": {
            "priceFormat": {
                "decimal": " "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `TrimStrings` will remove the space, may I ask why you need to allow a space like that? What is it used for? I think you could improve it, so it is a code smell that something is not right

Comment: ``decimal`` can be anything even space, and space is rlly common value :/, i can fake it to passing to it something like ``value:|#| |#|`` and then handle it in backend but its terrible workaround

Answer (score 0):

1 - Generate the middleware using Artisan:

```
php artisan make:middleware TrimDecimalSpaces
```

2 - Open the generated middleware file (TrimDecimalSpaces.php) and modify it to suit your needs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest;

class TrimDecimalSpaces extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'numbering.invoice.priceFormat.decimal',
    ];
}
```

3 - Register the middleware in the Kernel.php file:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimDecimalSpaces::class,
    // ...
];
```

This custom middleware extends `*TransformsRequest*`, which is the base class used by Laravel for request transformations, including trimming. By adding the specific parameter to the $except array, you tell Laravel not to trim spaces in this particular parameter.

Comment: this doesnt help cuz i tryed remove "TrimStrings" that cause all trimming in laravel and it doesnt wokred at all, how this can solve my issue ?

Comment: Make sure the custom middleware is registered after Laravel's built-in middleware, specifically after the `TrimStrings` middleware. The order of middleware execution matters.

Comment: Like this I edit the answer please check at the last for the registration at point 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; now that you've been posting for a couple of weeks you must be aware of the site policy that [bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) so-called "AI" generated content. Please keep this policy in mind for the future. Thanks!